# Parsing Parameter from Code behind to DataNavigateURLFormatString in ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-core, iis

i have a folder structure like D/temp/bplantest/F/9000 and my asp file has to be located in the "bplantest" folder because the subfolders (here for example "9000") are dynamic and changing. In the "9000" folder users find the hyperlinks to all files in it and should be able to download it. Because the hyperlinks leads directly to the root folder of the aspx file i tryed to use DataNavigateUrlFormatString.
It is working for the hard coded value DataNavigateUrlFormatString="F/9000/{0}" but i need the "F/9000" replaced by the value from getFolder because the folder names are changing and has to be dynamic.

I´m completely new to asp and vb.net so i would really appreaciate if someone could help me out.
It would be no problem if the solution is in C#

Thanks!

Here is my file:

```
 <%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>


<script language="VB" runat="server">
  Sub Page_Load(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
    Dim getFolder as String = Request.QueryString("id")
    Dim dirInfo as New DirectoryInfo("D:\temp\bplantest\" + getFolder)

    
    articleList.DataSource = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*")
    articleList.DataBind()
  End Sub
 
</script>



<asp:DataGrid runat="server" id="articleList" Font-Name="Verdana"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingItemStyle-BackColor="#eeeeee"
    HeaderStyle-BackColor="Navy" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
    HeaderStyle-Font-Size="15pt" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="True">
  <Columns>
    <asp:HyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlField="Name" DataTextField="Name" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="F/9000/{0}"
           HeaderText="File Name" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="LastWriteTime" HeaderText="Last Write Time"
        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Length" HeaderText="File Size"
        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" 
        DataFormatString="{0:#,### bytes}" />
  </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

Replace asp:HyperLinkColumn  with Template Column which contain HyperLink.

```
 <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn   HeaderText="File Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink id="hlkName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("{0}", getFolder) + "/" + Eval("Name") %>'
                   />
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateColumn>

    </Columns>
```

In code behind, declare variable getFolder which you need to set in Page_Load Event

```
Public getFolder As String
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    getFolder = "folder"        
End Sub
```

This variable is replace in Hyperlink at the time of rendering.